# What is the correct way to change the config of a new Gerrit project?

Tags: gerrit

I have multiple projects that I need to create under `Gerrit` (I am owner/root).

My gerrit location is /home/gerrit/

The first project was created under `/home/gerrit/review_site/`.
(pointing to git repo in `/var/www/gitrepos`)

When I create a second project from the Gerrit Web interface (Create Project link), I inherit the All-Projects project --
I think from (`review_site/etc/gerrit.config`).

It gives me a choice to inherit from another project, but there is no relevant parent project, as this second project has different options mostly (different groups, etc.).

I don't see any way to configure options during the Create Project step.

Once the project is created, I see that it shares the /`home/gerrit/review_site/ folder` (and so shares logs, etc.)

What is the best way to change the new project's config? I can clone the git repo, upload the changes through Gerrit. But can I change the directory and other details from under it?

Which config file should it use and how do I specify it? Do I need to restart the Gerrit server as the config file will then be changed? At the moment, I'm not sure what the architecture should be:
- should each project be in a different directory? (`/home/gerrit/project1, /home/gerrit/project2, ...?)`

Any help wrt how to manage separate projects in `Gerrit` would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't associate different "gerrit.config" configurations for different projects (repositories). The GERRIT-SITE/etc/gerrit.config file is a unique configuration file for the Gerrit server not for a specific project. [These](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/project-configuration.html#project_options) are the project options you can set.

The local filesystem directory where the Git repositories are created is configurated using the gerrit.basePath option in the GERRIT-SITE/etc/gerrit.config file. See more info [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-gerrit.html#gerrit).

Comment: Thank you for the response.  What I'm still wondering about, though, and my original point, is that if my projects require different settings which are not in the configurable list (e.g. ldap server), then do I need to have a completely separate, second Gerrit instance?

Comment: This is true but... why would you like to have (for example) a different LDAP server for a different project (repository)? This doen't make sense. I think you will not need any different gerrit.config setting for any project.

Comment: Unfortunately, we do -- for example, we're trying to import a project from another external server. It's taking very long (many weeks) due to issues. We needed to point our authentication to external servers for that project. We can't run/support the other local project in the meanwhile.